# Javascript does not seem to be called

Tags: javascript, html, head

im having a problem with a javascript file possibly failing to load or containing errors

HTML Code:

```
 <head>
    <title>TEMPLATE</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="author" content="Adam Bullock">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Javascript Code:

```
/* 


* NavBar_ArrowSlider moves an arrow depending on the users move selection on
 * the navigation bar
 * 
 * The script takes a position an moves the slider image to a set margin
 * 
 * NavElement - number of list item
 * MouseEvent - if users moves out of the name bar the icon will move back to
 * its default position
 * DefaultPosition - number of list item
 */
function navBar_arrowSlider(navElement, mouseEvent, defaultPosition) {
    var arrow = document.getElementById(navBarSlider);
    var navElementPosition = ["90px","295px","493px","695px"];
    // DEBUG
    alert("Positon:" + navElement + " Move Event:" + mouseEvent + " default position:" + defaultPositon);
    // END OF DEBUG
    if (mouseEvent === "mouseOver") {
        var position = navElementPosition[navElement];
        arrow.style.marginLeft=navElementPosition;
    } else {
        var position = navElementPosition[defaultPosition];
        arrow.style.marginLeft=navElementPosition;
    }    
}
```

im at a lost as to why this is not working, because i cant seem to see any errors atm, bare in mind i have been working solid for the past 14 hours :/ life of a programmer

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Bull

Comment: try to split that code <script src="js/main.js">navBar_arrowSlider(0,'moveOver',0)</script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have JavaScript code in `<script>` tags that loads external JavaScript. You need to break them up:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">navBar_arrowSlider(0,'moveOver',0)</script>
```

Comment: also, will that fire off if the element doesn't exist yet?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what that script does so I can't say for sure if they would need to wrap that code so it only fires after the dom is ready.

Comment: Right. I saw this: document.getElementById(navBarSlider); but since I don't know what's been done yet I don't know. If, however, he is expecting this to work on markup in the body at this point it will fail. He'd have to do as you say and wrap it on dom load.

Answer (score 1):

A `<script>` element can have **either** a "src" attribute or JavaScript content, but not both.

Comment: edited the original post, that must have been a paste error. my bad